# find the distribution of composed random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let X be a random Variable with strictly positive PDF $f_X : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow (0,  \infty)$ and CDF $F_X$. Find the distribution of of the random variables $F_X(X) = F_X \circ X$

I've just started on random variables so any idea how to tackle this?

Comment: This has been asked and answered many times here, but even if that was not the case, you would be unlikely to get a positive response without showing context or what you have tried

Comment: Hint : assume that $F_X$ is invertible (i.e. that $F_X^{-1}$ exists) and for any $t\in\mathbb R$ compute the probability $$\mathbb P(F_X(X)\le t) $$

Comment: There is not enought information to answer this question as written.

Comment: I understood the exact same assignment that stated that the random variable X had a uniform distribution $U_{[a,b]}$, and I found that $ F_X(X) = F_X \circ X = $ $\mathbb{1}_{[1, \infty)} (t)$, but this is a bit too theoretical as it says nothing about the distribution of X.